# Where can i download Qt Bridge for photoshop?

Tags: qt

I downloaded qt design studio, I have photoshop installed but I can't find the plugin, looking at the tutorial https://doc.qt.io/qtdesignstudio/qtbridge-ps-setup.html only the installer program is provided and not the plugin

Comment: This is the wrong StackExchange site for software and library requests. The proper site is [http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @drescherjm I'm not looking for any software, I'm looking for a part of the missing development environment that I can't find anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, qt bridge is not available in community version